# Count the number of nodes in the list that have the same data as the last node in Linear Linked List recursively

Tags: c++, recursion

I'm practicing LLL recursion and I'm currently stuck on this problem. Here is what I have so far:

```
count_last(node* head, int &last_node_data)
{
     if(!head) return 0;
     if(!head->next)
     {last = head->data;
       return 0;
     }
      count_last(head->next,last);
      if(head->data == last)
           //Increase count by 1;
  }
```

How do I increase the count? I really struggle when working backward with recursion (from the end of the list). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- Use a static local variable (one-shot use only since it will never re-initialize)
- Use a global variable
- Pass the count as a parameter, return the updated count.
- Pass a pointer to the count as a parameter, update it

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
int count_last(node* head, int &last_node_data)
{
    if (!head) return 0;

    // if you don't want to include the last
    // node in the count, you can filter it out...
    //
    // if (!head->next) return 0;

    return ((head->data == last_node_data) ? 1 : 0) + count_last(head->next, last_node_data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will this work if last_node_data is unknown until traverse?